# Exporting grid data to excel. Open excel file before before saving

Tags: c#, excel, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am exporting gridview data to excel using infragistics excel exporter. Everything is working fine and data is exported and file is saved on local disk.

But i want to view/open the file before or after export happens. How can I do that. So that I can save my file to a proper location whereever I need to save as

My code is as below

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.UltraGridExcelExporter1.Export(Me.grdiView1, "C:\GridData.xls")
End Sub
```

Comment: Before running the Export method open a SaveFileDialog and asks your users where they want to save the incoming file. Then use the user selection replacing your hardcoded filename.

Comment: Tried this `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\GridData.xls")`

Comment: @Steve Can you help to send some sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before running the Export method open a SaveFileDialog and ask your users where they want to save the incoming file. Then use the user selection replacing your hardcoded filename

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using sfd = New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        sfd.AddExtension = True
        sfd.Filter = "Excel file (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx"
        If DialogResult.OK = sfd.ShowDialog() Then
            Me.UltraGridExcelExporter1.Export(Me.grdiView1, sfd.Filename)
            if DialogResult.Yes = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to open the file", "Excel", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo Then
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sfd.FileName)
            End If 
        End If
    End Using 
End Sub
```